# Swift App Extension: instance method count is unavailable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, ios-app-extension

I just create my first app extension using XCode 7.1. One code file containing the code below is shared with both targets:

```
var str  = "";
var l = str.count; //Compile error for extension target App: count is unavailable: There is no ...
```

The reason for this compile error seams to be that App extension compiles with swift 1.2 while the container target compiles with swift 2.0.

One solution would be importing the content App into the extension App doesn't appear to be a good solution from what i read about it. Sharing the code between targets can be difficult if both are not compiled using the same compiler.

I just run through all target settings and didn't find nothing that could be changed.

Can't find any post about this problem, witch is not so uncommon, so it is must likely i am interpreting something in a wrong way.

The only solution i can think of is using NSString instead of String but that is just an workaround for one class type. More problems of this kind will emerge in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 2 it's

```
str.characters.count
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.characters.count` to get `String` length in Swift 2

Comment: count() was created by me as an extension. I feel so bad.